# Specify prefix for Django auth tables

Tags: django, django-admin

Can I specify a prefix for auth_*   tables of Django Auth. I want to add django_ to all django tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good and right thing to do, since specifying/setting table prefixes was proposed and rejected several times:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/388
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/891
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5000
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13176
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15238

Though there are some third-party apps that uses [class_prepared](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#class-prepared) signal in order to change table names while models are defined and registered, take a look:

- https://github.com/benslavin/django-db-prefix
- https://github.com/pydevua/django-table-prefix

Hope that helps.